What's the right way to configure Jodit toolbar buttons with custom order and grouping?
I want to configure jodit to use specific buttons in order and groupings of my choice.
For example:
( Undo - Redo - Separator ) group ; ( Bold - Italic - Underline - Separator ) group; Etc.
While also having the option to mix in custom buttons.
How can I accomplish this?
I tried both using the 'buttons' option in the Jodit make configuration, which makes it easy to include default buttons, and include custom buttons as well, but does not allow me to make groupings.
buttons: [
  'undo',
  'redo',
  'italic',
  'bold',
  { name: 'foo', text: 'bar', exec: () => { ...}
]

I also tried using this method:
editor.toolbar.build([
  new UIGroup(
    editor, 
    [editor.toolbar.buttons.find(b => b.name === 'undo')],
    { name: 'undo' }
  ),
  new UIGroup(
    editor, 
    [editor.toolbar.buttons.find(b => b.name === 'redo')],
    { name: 'redo' }
  ),
  new UIGroup(
    editor, 
    [new UISelect(
      editor, 
      {
        name: 'select-dropdown',
        options: [
          { value: 'a', text: 'a' }, 
          { value: 'b', text: 'b' }, 
          { value: 'c', text: 'c' }, 
        ]
      }
    )],
    { name: 'select-dropdown' }
  ),

by using the Jodit provided UI system and this would let me use easily default buttons and include separators/groupings by using the UISeparator, but UIButton does not have the 'exec' property, so I do not know if it is possible to add custom functionality. It is also incredibly unwieldy and also apparently the UISelect is not working as expected:
Screenshot
What is the correct way of doing this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

I find it a bit unclear if you want a visual separation or an actual grouping with drop-down. For just a visual separation it is possible to use dividers of some kind, example with | between buttons or --- for separation:
  buttons: [
    'undo',
    'redo',
    '|',
    'italic',
    'bold',
    '---',
    { name: 'foo', text: 'bar', exec: () => {} },
  ],

It is also possible to group buttons with a drop down, or if you want to group them together so that they do not separate in smaller windows 'group:' can be used. I will provide an example, you list buttons together but add any custom functionality at controls:
const editor = Jodit.make('#editor', {
      buttons: [
        'fontsize',
        '|',
        {
          name: 'group1',
          text: 'Group 1',
          list: {
            undo: 'undo',
            redo: 'redo',
            customButton1: 'Custom 1',
          },
        },
        {
          name: 'group2',
          text: 'Group 2',
          id: '2',
          class: 'gr-2',
          list: {
            bold: 'bold',
            italic: 'italic',
            underline: 'underline',
            customButton2: 'Custom 2',
          },
        },
        '---',
        {
          group: 'group3',
          buttons: ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'customButton1']
        },
      ],
      controls: {
        customButton1: {
          text: 'Custom Button 1',
          exec: () => {
            editor.value = 'Hello';
          },
        },
        customButton2: {
          text: 'Custom Button 2',
          class: 'btn-2',
          exec: () => {
            editor.s.insertHTML('<p>Hello</p>');
          },
        },
      },
    });


This is honestly what I was looking for, the ability to customize the toolbar groupings and buttons the way I like. Where did you find this information? '|' and '---' "magic strings" for separators and blank space I would have never figured out.

The documentation is lacking details so I have every now and then found solutions along the way when trying to implement Jodit. When trying to answer your question I found out about '---' and 'group:' as I myself only used '|' and 'list:' for grouping buttons thus far.
About '---' I found it through reading a GitHub issue and the fix:
https://github.com/xdan/jodit/issues/713
https://github.com/xdan/jodit/commit/527f82bed366a4d55c57efb9fe764ed28f82bc16
The '---' will push the buttons after it to the other side of the toolbar so keep that in mind. If just a split then '|' is better.
